# Iterating through a column in a power bi query and storing some of those values in a new column

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a column  These values are lying in sets of 2, representing upper and lower tolerance values (in the same column, unfortunately). They follow the pattern : upper, lower, upper, lower, ... and so on. I would like to loop through this column and print the lower tol values in a new column called lower tol.

There is no specific manner to detect a lower tol value, since both are plain numbers for the machine. However, as the pattern suggests, every alternate value would be a lower tol value. So it can looped through accordingly. Is there a way to do this? If so, how would the M code/ power query code look like? Thank you!

ps. there are also some null values or alpha-numeric valyes lying in this column (not in the picture), which should be avoided by the loop. Thank you.

[image: here].

Comment: You could try to pivot/unpivot the columns into the right format, that would bring them into the same row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to (a) remove null rows (b) remove rows where the contents are not numeric (c) separate the remaining rows into two columns from alternating rows

To do this in easy steps:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each try [Column1] <> null and  Number.From([Column1])>0 otherwise false),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Inserted Modulo" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Modulo", each Number.Mod([Index], 2), type number),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Modulo", "Custom", each if [Modulo]=1 then [Index] else null),
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom1",{"Custom"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filled Down",{"Index"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns", {{"Modulo", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns", {{"Modulo", type text}}, "en-US")[Modulo]), "Modulo", "Column1", List.Sum),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Custom"})
in  #"Removed Columns1"
```

[image]

| Column1 |
| --- |
| A123 |
| B1234 |
| 1 |
| 5 |
| A1234 |
|  |
| 6 |
| 13 |
| 25 |
|  |
|  |
| A1234 |
| 38 |

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for your response. Yes, that's pretty much how I want it, except in power bi query editor. I am not sure how much of this is compatible with the power query language. Does look similar though. Highly appreciate this.

Comment: Good to hear. Thanks

Comment: Next time please post the sample input as text, similar to how I did, and include all the parts you need without  (not in the picture) which is not helpful

Comment: Will do, thakns! @horseyride

Comment: is there a way so that the existing columns are retained? The current manner gets rid of the original columns. Thanks!

Comment: Stop at the #"Removed Columns" step and remove all steps below .  Then filter on the modulo column for either the 0 or the 1 depending on which you want (first or last value). That will preserve all the columns